# Call to member function, in a class. PHP

Tags: php

I'm receiving this error, I know there are multiple topics about this already but I couldn't find a proper solution for mine.

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ELO-Alfa\dev\app\helpers\db.inc.php:28

line 28:

```php
    public function query($sql, $array = []){

        $this->dbQuery = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sql);
        $this->dbQuery->execute($array);

    }
```

This is the function that calls the query

```php
    public function getDay(){

        global $db;

        $db->query('SELECT * FROM day');

        $day = $db->getAll();

        foreach($day as $days):?>

            <th><?= $days['day_name'] ?></th>

        <?php endforeach;

    }
```

And this the echo

```php
<?= $agenda->getDay();?>
```

connection

````php
    public function connection(){

        try{
            $this->dbConnect = new PDO('mysql:host:' . $this->dbHost . ';dbname:' . $this->dbName,
                $this->dbUser,
                $this->dbPass);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Maybe `$this->dbConnect()->prepare($sql);` ? Not sure without seeing it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver dbQuery is NULL, yea I have changed it to that, but still the same

Comment: Then `$this->dbConnect()` is not returning an object.

Comment: I have updated my code, I included the connection function.

Comment: I don't see the `connection()` function called anywhere in your code. It needs to be called before any `query()` else `dbConnect` will be `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @JiriTousek Nevermind got it, thanks